# Inserting records to one object from different Visual Force pages using custom controller?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have Custom object Books__c and having fields like Book_name__c, Author__c and Price__c.  I want to store Book Name from one VF Page, Author Name from second VF page and Price from third VF page and then save.
How it possible using custom controller?

Comment: I am afraid the info is not detailed enough to help understand the issue. Can you please post more information about the issue and what have you done so far. Also just a question- Are you creating a visualforce page for each field?

Comment: Yes i am creating a visual force page for each field...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for a wizard kind of thing in VisualForce. The force.com cookbook has a great example to start with creating Visualforce page wizards.

http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/creating-a-wizard-with-visualforce-pages

You will need to maintain the state of each record as steps are completed, in order to support partial completion of wizard.

Hope this helps.